# Why is $\sqrt{x} =- 1$ extraneous?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

An equation is extraneous if (at least to my understanding) it has no valid solutions. The example my math teacher used was $\sqrt{x}=-1$, citing this proof

$$\sqrt{x}=-1 \\ x=1$$

They then stated that $\sqrt{1} \ne -1$, and therefor the equation is extraneous. While this wasn't initially a problem, I seemed to accept it for some reason, I now realize that $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$, and therefor -1 *is* a square root of 1, so why is the initial equation extraneous?

Am I missing something major here or was my math teacher wrong?

Comment: The function $\sqrt{x}$, when used in the real numbers, is defined as the non-negative solution $y$ to $x=y^2$. Since $-1$ is not non-negative, $\sqrt{x}=-1$ won't ever happen in the real numbers.

Comment: it is $(\pm 1)^2 =1$ and not $\sqrt 1=\pm 1$

Comment: We say **solutions** are extraneous.

Comment: It is a matter of convention.  The usual convention when dealing with the real numbers is that $\sqrt{}$ denotes the nonnegative square root.  On the other hand, in the context of complex numbers $\sqrt{}$ is often taken to be a multivalued function.

Comment: Note that the square root of a number's square is equal to the absolute value of that number. That is why, when you have $x^2=1$, the answer is $x=\pm 1$. But when you square a number's square root, the result is always that number, and not its absolute value.

Comment: As has been pointed out, it is just a matter of definition. The square root of a real number $x$ is just defined to be the non-negative number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. The reason many students gets confused is that they are so used to solving equations by e.g. squaring/taking the root of each side. So solving $a^2=b$ for $a$ yields $a=\pm \sqrt{b}$. But that is just because both $-\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ solves the equation. So do not get these things confused. For a real number $x$, $\sqrt{x}$ is always non-negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We talk about an *extraneous* or *spurious* solution when we solve an algebraic equation by raising both sides to some power. The map $x\mapsto x^n$ is not injective, hence once the original problem has been reduced to finding the roots of some polynomial, it is not granted that *every* root of such polynomial is indeed a solution of the original equation. For instance
$$ \sqrt{x-1} = 7-x \tag{1}$$
implies 
$$ x-1 = (x-7)^2 \tag{2}$$
and 
$$ p(x) = (x-7)^2-(x-1) = x^2-15x+50 = 0 \tag{3} $$
but while $x=5$ is an actual solution of $(1)$, the other root of $p(x)$,  i.e. $x=10$, is a *spurious* solution, because it fulfills $(2)$ but not $(1)$.

It is enough to recall that the very *definition* of the square root function over the real numbers:

> **Def**. $\sqrt{x}$ is the only non-negative real number whose square equals $x$.

In particular the maximal domain of the square root function is the set of non-negative real numbers, and over such set the square root function is non-negative. So $\sqrt{1}=1$, not $\pm 1$.

Over the set of complex numbers, for any $z\neq 0$ there are two opposite numbers whose squares equal $z$: in such context we write $\sqrt{z}=\pm w$ by meaning that both $w$ and $-w$ are roots of the polynomial $q(t)=t^2-z$, i.e. we regard $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as a multi-valued function: not a function, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 8):

> I now realize that $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$

You are mistaken. The square root symbol $\sqrt{\phantom0}$
denotes the positive square root function.
Therefore $\sqrt1 = 1 \neq -1.$

A point of confusion is that we often look at equations such as
$$
x^2 = 4
$$
and observe that they have two solutions, $x = \pm 2.$
But this does not say that $\sqrt4$ is "equal" to $\pm 2$;
the actual solution is
$$
x = \pm \sqrt4,
$$
where $x$ is an unknown. The $\pm$ sign tells us that $x$ might be $2$ or might be $-2.$
We need the $\pm$ sign in front of $\sqrt4$ to tell us that, because
$\sqrt4$ by itself is always $2,$ never $-2.$

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ means that, if $x$ is a non-negative real number, then $\sqrt{x}$ is the single non-negative real number which becomes $x$ when you square it. This is because $\sqrt{x}$ is more useful when it's a function, so each $x$ input needs to have at most one output.

However, when you use the square root to solve an equation, for example $x^2 = 1$, you need to recognize that undoing a square means you could have started with a positive *or* a negative number, because squaring either will make it positive. So, we say $x = \pm 1$ in this case, but $\sqrt{1}$ is still just $1$.

Comment: "the single real number that become x when you square it"?

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thanks for catching that, I said it in my head but it didn't come out of my fingers!

Comment: It should still be "$\sqrt{x}$ is the non-negative real number which..."

Comment: @qbert: I simply mean that it is unique (there is only one) and that $\sqrt{x}^2= \sqrt{x}\sqrt{x} = x$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Sorry, yes, I deleted that comment now, since AlexanderJ93 had just updated his answer, and I had not catched that yet.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 it also equals $(-\sqrt{x})(-\sqrt{x})$. Your edit makes it fine now though

Comment: Thanks everyone! I went a little too fast and missed out on precision. Everything should be in order now!